# Positioning element on top of full page slider

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I started off with a template from [Start Bootstrap's website](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/full-slider/).  The original design of the website has the navigation over the top of the slider with a dark grey opacity.

I have tried positioning the navigation as absolute, but it seems to just break it.  Any ideas?

Comment: You didnt said what do you need?

Comment: By slider, do you mean [carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/)?  Also, that example is not from Bootstrap's website, it's from Start Bootstrap, which is a repository of third-party Bootstrap templates.  You should post your HTML code - otherwise, it may help to simply view the source on the link I provided, which is a working example of the kind of behavior that you're looking for.